# Multiprocessing in python is the same as sequentially processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to print the numbers from 0 to 100000 sequentially and also using a processing pool of 12 processes.

```
def print1(x):
    print(x)

def print2(x):
    i = 0
    while(i < x):
        print(i)
        i+=1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start_time = time.time()
    p = Pool(12)
    p.map(print1, [i for i in range(100000)])
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    start_time = time.time()
    print2(100000)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

But it takes almost the same time and if you look at the cpu utilization is also the same.
On the left with multiprcessing and on the right sequentially
[image]

Why the CPU is using the same resources ?

Comment: Most of the time is spent printing, which is serialized through the terminal device.

Comment: But why the procesor is using multipe cores even when i don't use a processing pool?

Comment: There can be other things going on on the computer.